# How to detect/fix rounding errors in this 32-bit FP multiplication implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm, floating-point, multiplication, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand and implement 32-bit floating point multiplication. I'm using the IEEE 754 single-precision FP format whereby:

[image]

So I'm following [this walkthrough of the algorithm](http://lslwww.epfl.ch/pages/teaching/cours_lsl/sl_info/FPMultiplier.pdf). Using `bitstream.pack` I can convert a float to a string of bits in IEEE 754 format, so I'm doing that and comparing it to the result I get when I try to manually implement the algorithm.

However it looks like I'm getting rounding problems on both the mantissa and the exponent about 50% of the time. Can anyone see what I'm implementing incorrectly here? If not, is there a way to detect and correct these rounding errors?

```
import bitstring, random 

successes = 0
failures = 0

def ieee754(float):
    b = bitstring.pack('>f', float)
    sbit, wbits, pbits = b[:1], b[1:12], b[12:]
    return sbit.bin + wbits.bin + pbits.bin

def extract_parts(bits):
    m = bits[9:]     # 23 bits 0-22 are mantissa
    e = bits[1:1+8]  # 8 bits 23-31 are exponent
    s = bits[:1]     # bit 32 is sign
    return s, e, m 

tests = [(-18.0, 9.5), (134.0625, -2.25), (-14.5, -0.375), (7.5, 15.5), (1.2, 23.1), (-0.5, -0.2)]

for a, b in tests:
    #a = random.uniform(-10, 10)
    #b = random.uniform(-10, 10)

    a_s, a_e, a_m = extract_parts(ieee754(a))
    b_s, b_e, b_m = extract_parts(ieee754(b))

    # sign is exclusive-or of signs
    s = '1' if int(a_s) != int(b_s) else '0'

    # exponent is sum of exponents minus 127 'bias'
    e = int(a_e, 2) + int(b_e, 2) - 127

    # mantissa is product of mantissas with a 1 added as their MSB
    # then we ignore the MSB of the result
    m = '{0:023b}'.format(int('1' + a_m, 2) * int('1' + b_m, 2))[1:24]

    # convert to binary strings for comparison
    e = '{0:08b}'.format(e)

    print("Calculated:\t", (s, e, m));
    print("Expected:\t", extract_parts(ieee754(a*b)))

    if((s, e, m) == extract_parts(ieee754(a*b))):
        print("Success with", a, b); successes += 1
    else:
        print("Failure with", a, b); failures += 1

print("Successes", successes, "Failures", failures)
```

And these are my results:

```
Calculated:  ('1', '10000110', '01010110000000000000000')
Expected:    ('1', '10000110', '01010110000000000000000')
Success with -18.0 9.5

Calculated:  ('1', '10000111', '00101101101001000000000')
Expected:    ('1', '10000111', '00101101101001000000000')
Success with 134.0625 -2.25

Calculated:  ('0', '10000000', '01011100000000000000000')
Expected:    ('0', '10000001', '01011100000000000000000')
Failure with -14.5 -0.375

Calculated:  ('0', '10000100', '11010001000000000000000')
Expected:    ('0', '10000101', '11010001000000000000000')
Failure with 7.5 15.5

Calculated:  ('0', '10000011', '10111011100001010010000')
Expected:    ('0', '10000011', '10111011100001010001111')
Failure with 1.2 23.1

Calculated:  ('0', '01111011', '10011001100110011001101')
Expected:    ('0', '01111011', '10011001100110011001101')
Success with -0.5 -0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two (three?) issues that I see.

1. If the product of the significands is greater than or equal to 2, then the exponent is wrong. This explains the off-by-one errors in the exponents.
2. Instead of truncating the product of the significands, you need to apply round-to-even logic. This explains the off-by-one errors in the significands.
3. You're not handling subnormals, infinities, or NaN correctly (but you probably know that).

Comment: Thanks for your response! When you say the exponent is wrong, can you tell me what you mean? For these tests the product of the significands is always greater than or equal to two - how do I know whether I need to decrement it or increment it?

Comment: @crclayton You need to increment the exponent by one when the product of `int('1' + a_m, 2) * int('1' + b_m, 2)` has more digits than expected (i.e., is greater than or equal to `2**(23*2+1)`).

Comment: That makes sense now! I was reading about normalization but I didn't understand how to detect it, thank you very much.